# Probability a randonly chosen baby weight greater than $y$.

Tags: statistics

Summary statistics of birth weight of $30$ baby boys:
Mean: $3510.567$
Standard Deviation: $a = 290.1037$

Assume that birth weight of baby boy born in the Rose Women's and Children's Hospital (denote by $y$) follows a normal distribution with a mean of $3400$ grams and a standard deviation that agrees with the standard deviation given in summary statistics.

i) Write down the value of $y$ where $y$ is $1$ standard deviation smaller than the population mean. Identify and estimate the probability that the birth weight of a randomly chosen baby boy born in the Rose Women's and Children Hospital is greater than this value of $y$.

$y= 3400- 290.1037= 3109.8963. $I found value of $y$ but I'm not sure how to continue from here. Do I use $z= \frac{\overline x- \mu }{a}$ ?

Comment: ii) Use the Central Limit Theorem to estimate the probability that the sample mean is greater than or equal to the mean as shown in summary statistics.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time, and also if you wanted to ask this why haven't you included it in the original question?

Comment: Just wanna check if i am correct for part ii):  z=(xbar-miu)/(standard dev/sqroot of n) which is (3510.567-3400)/(290.1037/sqroot of 30) = 2.0875 round up to 2.09. 2.09 in z table is 0.4817. They want to find greater or equal to so i use 0.5- 0.4817 = 0.0183 or 1.83% (answer)

Answer (score 1):

**Clues:**

***Rough idea:*** If $W$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and SD $\sigma$, then
$$P(\mu - \sigma < W < \mu + \sigma) 
= P(-1 < Z < 1) \approx 0.68,$$
where $Z = (W-\mu)/\sigma$ has a standard normal distribution. Then, by symmetry,
$$P(W < \mu - \sigma) = P(W > \mu - \sigma)\\ \approx (1-.68)/2 =0.16.$$
Roughly speaking 68% of the probability is within
one standard deviation of the mean, 16% is below $\mu - \sigma$ and 16% is above $\mu + \sigma.$

***Actual problem:*** Now, it seems you are asked to use the random variable $Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=3400,\sigma=290.1037)$ and to find
$P(Y > 3400 + 290.1037).$ Can you use normal probability tables to find an (almost) exact value?

**Addendum:** Directly in R, where `pnorm` is a normal CDF, without standardizing or using printed tables:

```
mu = 3400;  sg = 290.1074
1 - pnorm(mu+sg, mu, sg)
[1] 0.1586553
```

Comment: Fixed JaX typo.